# Converting this line of code to a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, increment

So in java, This is what I'm trying to execute:

```
num [0]=list.get(2);
num [1]=list.get(4);
num [2]=list.get(6);
num [3]=list.get(8);
```

I have an arraylist of integers called list and I want to put the values that are in the even number indices starting at 2 into an array of integers called num in the indices 0,1,2,3,etc. My problem is, I'm trying to do this within a for loop but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is what I have:

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size()-2; i++){
            num[i] = list.get(i+2);

        }
```

My problem here is, after incrementing i, my arraylist goes to the next index also instead of every other index. I've tried multiple variations of this loop but I keep coming to the same problem.

Comment: `list.get(i*2)`

Comment: should it be starting with `get(0)`?

Comment: the pairs algorithm is 2n, not n+2, so instead of i+2 use i*2 (add or substract an offset if you don't want to start at 0

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger no, I want to start at get(2).

Comment: is this homework ?

Comment: then I would use two variables as indices (`i` and `j`); one for the array, the other for the list. Start each with the appropriate value, increment one by 1 and the other by 2; and better check both limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int max = list.size()/2;
if(list.size()%2==0) max-=1; // prevents IndexOutOfBounds for even list lengths
for (int i=0; i<max; i++){
    num[i] = list.get(i*2 + 2);
}
```

Comment: if size is even it will fail: `size=8` -> `i<4` -> `i*2+2=8` -> IndexOutOfRangeException: 8

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, e.g. `list.size() = 10` means largest `i` is `4`, and `i*2 + 2 = 4*2 + 2 = 10` --- *Assuming* `num` array is created with correct size, it would be easier to just do `i<num.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

`for (int i=0,j=0; i<list.size()-2; i+=2,j++){
    num[j] = list.get(i+2);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

The loop should continue as long as the **`i`** is less then `(list.size()-1)/2`

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
int size = (list.size()-1)/2;
int[] num = new int[size];

for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
  num[i] = list.get(i*2+2);
}
System.out.println("num="+ Arrays.toString(num));
```

Here is [DEMO](http://ideone.com/qifcgc)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size() - 2; i++)
      num[i] = list.get((i * 2) + 2);
```

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, e.g. `list.size() = 10` means largest `i` is `7`, and `i*2 + 2 = 7*2 + 2 = 16`